# Argument #1 ($storeId) must be of type int, string given error

Tags: php, magento2.4.6, php8.1, function

I am having a feed which is run every night with crons. My instance is magento 2.4.6-p2.

I am using this **function** to get store id:

```
public function execute()
    {
        foreach ($this->storeManager->getStores() as $store) {
            // Only generate feeds when feed notification is active
            if ($this->coreConfig->isDailyFeedActive($store->getId())) {
                $this->logger->debug('MyModule: Nightly Feeds being run for Store View ' . $store->getId());
                $this->feedRunner->allFeeds($store->getId());
            }
        }
    }
```

But it return error when cron run:

```
Argument #1 ($storeId) must be of type int, string given
```

I can't figure out what I do wrong and I can't get the **store id**. Instead of getting a number I get a **string** as error says

Any help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `$store->getId()` method returns a `string` value. You should convert this value to an integer using `(int)$store->getId()` to match the method's requirement.

You can optimize your code with the following implementation:

```
public function execute()
{
    $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores();
    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        $storeId = (int)$store->getId();
        // Only generate feeds when feed notification is active
        if ($this->coreConfig->isDailyFeedActive($storeId)) {
            $this->logger->debug('MyModule: Nightly Feeds being run for Store View ' . $storeId);
            $this->feedRunner->allFeeds($storeId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it throws error: `Warning: Undefined variable $store` in this line: `foreach ($store as $store) {`

Comment: @G.G. there is a typo, please replace `foreach ($store as $store) {` with `foreach ($stores as $store) {`

Answer (score 1):

```
Argument #1 ($storeId) must be of type int, string given
```

> **The above error indicates that you are trying to use a variable as an argument for a function or method that expects an integer (int) as the first argument, but you are passing a string instead.You can use type hints to specify the expected data type for function or method arguments. If a function expects an argument of type int, you should pass an integer value, not a string.**

> The $store->getId() method returns a value as a string, which is not acceptable for your isDailyFeedActive() and allFeeds() methods. To resolve this, you should convert the string value into an integer using the int() PHP function.

```
$storeId = (int)$store->getId();
$this->coreConfig->isDailyFeedActive($storeId);
```

OR

```
$this->coreConfig->isDailyFeedActive((int)$store->getId());
```

**You have to use PHP 8 in Magento 2.4.6.**